# What is the best way to handle async code when I need to export a synchronous function?

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, asyncstorage

I am working on an app in React Native. I want to create a preconfigured axios instance that will have a JWT bearer token attached and have a handler to process 401 errors. I need to be able to fetch the users token from AsyncStorage but I can't initialize axios until I have the token. I don't want to use async/await with a [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) function as then I must export a promise. What is the best way, if possible, to avoid exporting a promise? The only answers I can find only are "Just use top level await" which does not work with React Native or "just use an async function" which returns a promise which I want to avoid.

```
import Axios from "axios";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
// This is an async function
const token = AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
const axios = Axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3000",
    headers: {
        // Token is undefined as promise is not yet resolved
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
});

// I want to avoid exporting a promise
export default axios;
```

Comment: There is no way. Even top level await is still just resolving a promise. You can't magically synchronise async code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for your quick reply! This is what I suspected. I was just hoping there was some straightforward way that I was forgetting about where I wouldn't have to export a promise.